# Help interpretting the following identity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, computational-physics, greens-functions

Basically, I am calculating a tunneling current for Cooper pairs, and I plan to write some code to simulate a related STM experiment. I went through a lengthy calculation involving temperature Green functions and analytic continuations to get my expression.

The issue is I am going to need to take the imaginary part of an expression involving the product of a bunch of complex functions, and so I rewrote the free propagator found in my final expression as:
$$        \frac{1}
        {\omega-\omega'-i\epsilon}
        =
        \frac{\omega-\omega'}{(\omega-\omega')^2+\epsilon^2}
        +
        \frac{i\epsilon}{(\omega-\omega')^2+\epsilon^2}
        =
        \pi\delta_\epsilon(\omega-\omega')
        \Big(
        \frac{\omega-\omega'}{\epsilon}
        +i
        \Big)$$
I know this is a famous relation involving the principle part, but I need to work with a finite energy resolution for a simulation, so the delta function is a Lorentzian. Basically, I do not (think I) need to worry about the principle part since $\epsilon\rightarrow0$ is required to make this expression blow up.

I have an integral over $\omega'$ I want to collapse, but I am a bit unsure of what to make of an integral of the form:
$$
\int d\omega'\delta_\epsilon(\omega-\omega')f(\omega')\frac{\omega-\omega'}{\epsilon}
$$
The delta function is nonzero for a range of $\omega'$'s within $\epsilon$ of $\omega$, so I do not think I can just say this evaluates to zero with $\omega=\omega'$. It seems like that ratio in the integral will be of order $1$ due to the $\epsilon$ in the denominator, so I am not sure if I can simplify this further. I thought maybe replace $f(\omega)$ with its value in the middle of the interval, $f(\omega)$, then smear this out in someway, but this seems off too...

Any clarifications or work arounds would be nice!